# Using nth-child CSS selector with UiBinder in GWT

Tags: gwt, css-selectors

In my web app, I want to have a table where every other row is colored with a different background.  I am using GWT and so in my UiBinder file I have some style information like this:

```
<ui:style> 
  .productlist { 
    cursor: pointer; 
    width: 50em; 
    padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px; 
  }

  .productlist tr:nth-child(even) { 
    background-color: silver; 
  }
</ui:style>
```

I believe this is the correct CSS as it works in the browser.  However, when running the app in dev mode, I get a crash saying the CSS cannot be interpreted.  If I replace "even" with "5", I get an error saying the Uibinder expected <IDENT>.

Has anyone used the nth-child CSS selector with GWT before?

Comment: n-th child is part of CSS 3. It's not available in IE 8 and older. See [this overview](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild). GWT tries to be compatible with IE, too, so it's not unexpected, that this doesn't work. Would be nice though, if there's a workaround (I don't think the [literal function](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#Literal_function) will work here.)

Comment: In the issue listed in z00bs' answer there is a workaround but it doesn't work.  I guess the real workaround is to add the style to every other row programatically.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is a [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4422&q=child%20selector&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars).

You can work around this problem by escaping the parenthesis to avoid confusing the poor GWT CSS parser:

```
.productlist tr:nth-child\(even\) { 
    background-color: silver; 
}
```